# Javascript code availability for both window.load and document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need a function that needs to be executed on document.ready and available to window.onload function ...

How can I do that?

```
$(document).ready(function someFunction() {
    execute something and pass the results to window.load
}
);


$(window).load(Need results of somefunction);​
```

Comment: Do you need the results of someFunction, or someFunction itself to be available inside of window.load?

Answer (score 2):

You can share the result of a function call by assigning it to some variable in scope.

```
(function(){
   var result;
   $(document).ready(function(){
      result = 'something';
   });

   $(window).load(function() {
       console.log(result); //something
   });

}());
```

Answer (score 0):

When passing a `function()` parameter to things like `$(document).ready(fn)`, you are actually creating an unnamed function, an anonymous function. So, if you want to get the same result for both `$(document).ready` and `$(window).load`, you can create a named function (this is if you want to share the function itself):

```
function someFunction() {
    /* execute some code */
}

$(document).ready(someFunction);
$(window).load(someFunction);
```

Since I see that I've misunderstood your question firstly, let me solve that.

Having a variable in the scope of both functions will alow both of them to use it. So, since having a variable in the global namespace it's not a good practice, then we should use an unnamed functions to wrap your two functions inside it:

```
(function(){
  var accessible_var;
  $(document).ready( function() {
    accessible_var = "passed to load handler";
  } );

  $(window).load( function() {
    console.log(accessible_var);
  } );
})();
```

**You have to take care with these two handlers!**

> `document.ready` will fire when all the elements are in place, and they can be referenced in the JS code, but the content is not necessarily loaded.
>
> The `window.load`, however will wait for the page to be fully loaded, this includes inner frames, images etc.
>
> **Warning** - If you want to use the Height, Width properties of an image for example, then document.ready is a deal braker!!

(as it is written [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/632672/JavaScripts-document-ready-vs-window-load))

Comment: I mean you need to pass the function itself not the result of its invocation.

Comment: I am terribly tired, sorry :D

Comment: it doesn't have to be an unnamed function, such as in the OP's example. Semantics of course, :p

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to do something on dom ready, then access it on window load, nest the window load binding method inside the dom ready method.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // do something
    var somevar = "Hello World!";
    $(window).on("load", function () {
        console.log(somevar); // Hello World!;
    });
});
```